# Access to inherited children's variables of abstract class from another children of same abstract class

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

So, I have folowing problem:

I have abstract class with multiple children of this abstract class.
In my opinion, the best explanation is an example:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public $varialbe = false;

    abstract function process();
}

class Child1 extends AbstractClass
{
   public function process()
   {
      //some code here
   }
}

class Child2 extends AbstractClass
{
   public function process()
   {
      //!!!Problem is here = Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class AbstractClass
      $child1 = new Child1();

      //I need something like this:
      $child1->varialbe = $this->variable;
      $child1->process();
   }
}

$child2 = new Child2();
$child2->process();
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me! I do not get a fatal error.

The only thing I get is a notice because of the typo inside `$this->variable` in the child2 class. The original variable is incorrectly spelled "varialbe", but used consistently.

Fixing the typo lets the code run completely error-free.

So you fail to demonstrate the problem. Update your question if you find why the issue isn't included in your code. It must be somewhere else.

And make sure you actually run your code before using it as an example, and that it has the problem you describe.

Comment: Thanks. And sorry about that. I had a bad day - too much work.